# 2FA authentication on user level with Azure B2C active directory

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, 12factor

We have business application and currently we are implementing Azure B2C active directory. We will enable 2FA authentication in our login workflow but some of our customers would like to disable 2FA authentication.

Is it possible to Enable / disable 2FA on user level either through console or using Graph api? Our idea is that if it is possible, then we will not make 2FA authentication as part of the sign in workflow but will enable this feature on user profile level

Answer (score 0):

For the built-in flows, MFA is either on for all users or off for all users, so you'll have to create a custom policy that enables an end user (or you as administrator) to opt in to or out from MFA.

A good sample to refer to is [the "Sign in with MFA" sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone).

As well as offering both e-mail and/or phone MFA, you can add a default choice of "None".